# Reset user_id value in Firebase Analytics

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

Actual event logs taking a few hours to reflects on the dashboard. So I am using `DebugView` to analyse events.

My app has a login/logout feature. App can be used by multiple users.

On successful login, calling `FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(context).setUserId("user id")`.

Then after all the further logs goes under given user ID. Till now its good.
But If I login with different user then user id doesn't get change and all logs events goes under previous one.

How to reset User Id on each login call?

Answer (score 13):

You can remove the User ID by setting it to null or replace it with a new user ID. userID is just a user property that goes with all events after it is set so you need to set it to null when user logs out and set a new user ID when a different user logs in.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out.

Comment: Associated reference doc for citation is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics#public-void-setuserid-string-id)